# Swapping elements in a list based on their match in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, cryptography, cypher, alphabet

Alright so basically I'm trying to write a function that takes a string and a dictionary that relates every letter in the alphabet to another letter in the alphabet. The function then splits the string into individual letters, swaps them for their pair in the dictionary, then puts it all back together. 
It's important to note that in my dictionary the input alphabet is the values in the (key,value) pair and I'm trying to swap to the key alphabet.

```
def substitutor(text,theDict):
    for n in list(text):
        n = [key  for (key, value) in theDict.items() if value == n]
```

What I've tried here is to take every letter n in the list of letters "list(text)" and redefine it as the key in my (key,value) pair in the dictionary. 
I know I need to return something but I can't figure out what. The output ought to be either a list equivalent to list(text) but with the letters swapped or better yet a single string combining that list into one. I'm super new to python so I might be missing something obvious here, would love help.

Comment: please post a sample input and output

Comment: It makes no sense to assign to the interation variable.

Comment: Oh first note, why you defining variable index n with a list in 3rd line?

Comment: You don't need to convert a string to a list, you can use `for n in text:`

Comment: Why not make two dictionaries, one for each direction, so you don't have to search `theDict.items()`?

Answer (score 1):

Invert the dictionary, then use that to translate the elements of `text`.

```
def substitutor(text, theDict):
    rev_dict = {v: k for k, v in theDict.items()}
    return ''.join(rev_dict.get(c, '') for c in text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [str.translate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)

```
def substitutor(text,theDict):
    d = {ord(v): k for k, v in theDict.items()}
    return text.translate(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Is Incorrect, In First Place You Shouldn't Be Defining Iliteration Index (n here) With Something Else, **What You Can Do Is To Get Each Element Of String And Use It As Key To Dictionary To Get It's Encrypted Character!! **

For sample I put a one liner code for you, it will work accordingly your problem!!

```
def substitutor(text,theDict):
    encrypted_text = ''.join([ theDict.get(n) for n in list(text) if theDict.haskey(n) ])
    return encrypted_text
```